# How to make a switch function pull its criteria from a Spreadsheet/Form entry

Tags: google-apps-script

I am pretty new to Google Apps Scripts, and I'm having some trouble getting a part of my script to work. See the switch function below:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
 var emailSubject   = "Request for Sample";  

 // Set with your email address or a comma-separated list of email addresses.
 var yourEmail    = "staticemailgoeshere";

 // Set with your spreadsheet's key, found in the URL when viewing your spreadsheet.
 var docKey      = "SHEETKEYHERE";

 // If you want the script to auto send to all of the spreadsheet's editors, set this value as 1.
 // Otherwise set to 0 and it will send to the yourEmail values.
 var useEditors    = 0;

      switch () {
   case "Name 1":
      yourEmail = "emailaddress";
      break;
   case "name 2":
      yourEmail = "emailaddress";
      break;
   case "Name 3":
      yourEmail = "emailaddress";
      break;
   case "Name 4":
      yourEmail = "emailaddress";
      break;
   default:
      yourEmail = "defaultemail"
  }

 if (useEditors) {
  var editors = DocsList.getFileById(docKey).getEditors();
  if (editors) { 
   var notify = editors.join(',');
  } else var notify = yourEmail;
 } else {
  var notify = yourEmail;
 }


 // The variable e holds all the submission values in an array.
 // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
 var message = "";
 for(var i in headers) {
  message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + '\n\n'; 
 }


 MailApp.sendEmail(notify, emailSubject, message); 
}
```

Now, heres the thing. The statement above works as expected right now. Every time I choose a name from the list, it goes to default because I can't figure out how to get the function to read a certain field to pull the data from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` statement has an empty expression, so it will always execute the `default:` case. What is it supposed to be testing? And what is `e`, the (unused) argument to your function?